can't find docker-compose.yaml file in .ddev directory
I installed the latest ddev version (1.23.0) for developing my laravel project. I want to have a remote access through ssh to my vs code. For that reason, I suppose to have "docker-compose.yaml" file inside the .ddev directory. However, I haven't see anything like "docker-compose.yaml" file in the related directory (even if I ran command like ls -a to show every file and directory inside that directory).
I did 'ddev poweroff', followed by 'ddev config' to reconfigure it and then 'ddev start' but found no luck to find this file. I even remove the .ddev directory from my root directory of my project and reconfigure it, still haven't found it. I ran "ddev logs" to see if there is any irregularities on my ddev configuration but haven't found any issues.
My question is:

How can I mitigate this problem and is it a DDEV issue or a set up issue from my end?
Is there any other way how I can have a remote access to VS Code through ssh?



I installed DDEV on WSl2.
I used composer to handling dependencies.
laravel framework version - 11.5.0
composer version - 2.2.6
PHP version - 8.2.18


Why is this tagged with Composer and Laravel? Why do you even care about the files in the .ddev folder? Besides the configuration file, all others are internal

Most people use the vscode-ddev-manager extension with DDEV and vscode. Please give that a try and see how it works for you. The maintainer there does a fantastic job of responding to issues, so creating issues there is a great way to get support.
With DDEV the docker-compose configuration is generated, and it's in .ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-base.yaml, which is expanded to .ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml (both hidden files on macOS and Linux).
Neither of those is intended to be something you have to look at.
DDEV's configuration is done with .ddev/config.yaml.
Setting up vscode (on the Windows side) on WSL2 isn't hard, but it's complicated because of the many layers. Some of the steps especially for debugging are in docs.
